# How to convert Office files to PDF using Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I'm looking for a way to convert Office files to PDF.
I found out that Microsoft Graph could be used.

I'm trying to download converted PDF using Microsoft Graph from OneDrive.
I'd like to convert .docx to .pdf.

However, when I sent the following request, I did not receive a response even if I waited.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}/drive/root:/test.docx:/content?format=pdf
```

Also, the error code is not returned.
If syntax is wrong, an error code will be returned as expected.
It will not return only when it is correct.

In addition, I can download the file if I do not convert.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}/drive/root:/test.docx:/content
```

Is my method wrong or else I need conditions?
If possible, please give me sample code that you can actually do.

```
 using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authResult.AccessToken);
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(graphUrl);

            var result = await client.GetAsync("/v1.0/users/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/drive/root:/test.docx:/content?format=pdf");
            :
```

Answer (score 2):

I would like to elaborate a bit [Marc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52633131/1375553) by providing a few examples for [`HttpClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx).

Since *by default* for `HttpClient` [`HttpClientHandler.AllowAutoRedirect` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.allowautoredirect?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Net_Http_HttpClientHandler_AllowAutoRedirect) is set to `True` there is no need to explicitly follow HTTP redirection headers and the content could be downloaded like this:

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
     client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
     client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://graph.microsoft.com");

     var response = await client.GetAsync($"/v1.0/drives/{driveId}/root:/{filePath}:/content?format=pdf");

      //save content into file 
      using (var file = System.IO.File.Create(fileName))
      { 
           var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(); 
           await stream.CopyToAsync(file); 
      }
}
```

In case if follow HTTP redirection is *disabled*, to download the converted file, your app must follow the Location header in the response as demonstrated below:

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
    AllowAutoRedirect = false
};

using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler))
{
     client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
     client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://graph.microsoft.com");

     var response = await client.GetAsync($"/v1.0/drives/{driveId}/root:/{filePath}:/content?format=pdf");
     if(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Redirect)
     {
           response = await client.GetAsync(response.Headers.Location); //get the actual content
     }

      //save content into file 
      using (var file = System.IO.File.Create(fileName))
      { 
           var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(); 
           await stream.CopyToAsync(file); 
      }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. As the result, my network environment seems to be bad. So, I put it on Azure and it worked. I appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 1):

The API doesn't return the converted content directly, it returns a link to the converted file. From the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_get_content_format):

> Returns a `302 Found` response redirecting to a pre-authenticated download URL for the converted file.
>
> To download the converted file, your app must follow the `Location` header in the response.
>
> Pre-authenticated URLs are only valid for a short period of time (a few minutes) and do not require an Authorization header to access.

You need to capture the `302` and make a 2nd call to the URI in the `Location` header in order to download the converted file.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

As the result, my network environment seems to be bad.
So, I put it on Azure and it worked.

I appreciate it very much.

Comment: This seems to be broken currently or has been. For me, this call does not return a response with a location link. It returns a 200 with the entire converted file content.